# Multiple page print document in c#

Tags: c#, loops, recursion, printing

please some one help me , i have to print a document in multiple pages in c#, i went through internet then used this code but not working, (loop is again start after printing one page )

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);

            float pageWidth = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width;
            float pageHeight = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height;

            float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
            int startX = 40;
            int startY = 30;
            int offsetY = 40;


            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
            {

             graphic.DrawString("Line: " + i, font, brush, startX, startY + offsetY);
             offsetY += (int)fontHeight;

               if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
                {

                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    offsetY = 0;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uh.. this loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )`? Maybe because you have it statically set to loop 100 times.

Comment: Your i variable needs to be declared outside the PrintPage scope.  Use the BeginPrint event to set it to 0.  Now you have to break out of your loop when it hits the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you set `e.HasMorePages = true`, it will just fire the `printDocument1_PrintPage()` event handler again.  You need to keep a class variable for i, so that it won't restart at 0 every time the next page prints.  Don't declare it locally inside the event handler.

```
private class MyPrinter
{
    private int i = 0;

    private void Print()
    {
        i = 0;
        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
         .....
         .....
         .....

         while (i < 100)
        {
             graphic.DrawString("Line: " + i, font, brush, startX, startY + offsetY);
             offsetY += (int)fontHeight;

               if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
                {

                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    offsetY = 0;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;

                }
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Mangist! now multiple document can  be seen in printpreview when i click print button blank paper only comes please help me

Comment: #region print 
        private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.printDocument1.PrinterSettings = this.printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
                this.printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }
        #endregion

Comment: Are you calling the Print() method I wrote?  It needs to reset the variable i to 0 whenever you print the document.  Set a breakpoint on the graphic.DrawString() line and check the values of your X,Y coordinates and i.  Maybe add a Debug.WriteLine("Line " + i.ToString()") somewhere in that loop too.

Comment: OK now i called print() now nicely printing from print button but it displays in print preview but can not print and if i click print preview as second time disappear

Comment: every time i call print() but it wont work when i change i = 0 after e.HasMorePages = false,  loop never ends if (this.printPreviewDialog1 .ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.printDocument1.PrinterSettings = this.printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
                this.Print();
            }

Comment: Remove that i = 0 inside the loop, instead just call Print() whenever you need to print the document.  Learn how to use breakpoints and check the values of your variables.

Comment: i tried but so tired no gain anyhow thanks a lots if u can solve this problem me