# How Can I print to next page overflowed string?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, printing

I am trying to print a long list, Firstly I measured the string and via that, I prevent overflowing from the left side of the page but, I could not do that thing for the end of the page. It does not pass next page. How Can I do it ? Codes :

```
    private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listele();
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 10);
        Graphics gf = e.Graphics;
        SizeF sf = gf.MeasureString(textBox1.Text,printFont, 320);
        gf.DrawString(textBox1.Text, printFont, Brushes.Black,new RectangleF(new Point(60, 60), sf),StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    }
```

I added a screenshot to understand better. Thanks [SS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4U11.jpg)

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to print text as picture? User the proper tool for the job and you will have no problem. One good option is using a report.

Comment: No there is not a reason, just that is my first print experience :) I am trying to understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

The `PrintPage` event is raised for printing a *single page*. You need to measure your text/layout the page. If you measure and there is more than will fit on that page, you need to set the [`PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`, which will call the `PrintPage` event again.

It is up to you to keep track of which page you are printing and what will fit on that page. You have to measure the text and split it depending on what will fit on that page.

[Here is a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561611/multiple-page-print-document-in-c-sharp) that shows how to work with multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Graphics` to simply print out text is not your best option. As you figured out, there will be plenty of things that you need to deal with. Choose a better tool for your job. There is plenty of third party tools that you can use for that, but if you prefer using built-in tools, then try RLDC Reports.

From your toolbox, drop a `Report` and a `ReportViewer` on your form and make them hidden. Alternatively, you can create them in code instead of adding them to the UI.

Next, go through the lines in your `TextBox` (or better the source of those lines) and enter them in a `DataTable` with one column. Then Assign the `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property of the `Report`. If the source of lines in your `TextBox` is an `IEnumerable` object like `List<>`, then you don't need the above step and you can assign it directly to the `DataSource` property of the `Report`.

Finally, render the `Report` in the `ReportViewer` and print it out.

Here is a [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the PrintDocument.  Your way could work, but the user is trying to *learn* the basics of printing.  Your answer avoids that.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't say there was anything wrong with `PrintDocument`, I only commented on using `Graphics` to render text, which is not one of the basics of printing :).

Comment: Thanks, @LarsTech :) as you see my code is very simple. Those steps are a little bit high level for me for now :)