# Print out All images from bitmap Array in C#

Tags: c#, printdocument

I've been trying to print Bitmap Array image in C# (each index image should print separate page)

The length of the array is defined while running the program

Bitmap creating code:

```
Bitmap[] bitm = new Bitmap[dataGridView1.RowCount]
```

This code I used to  call print page event:

```
bitm[j].Save(@"Image/" + dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "Term Report.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
pictureBox2.Image = bitm[j];
pictureBox2.Width = bitm[j].Width;
pictureBox2.Height = bitm[j].Height;

myPrintDocument2.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
myPrinDialog2.Document = myPrintDocument2;
if (myPrinDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    myPrintDocument2.Print();
}
```

Print document's print page event:

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap2, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap2, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height));
        }
```

But it is displaying printdialog for each and every page. But I need all pages should print one printdialog!

Comment: You should subscribe to the `PrintPage` event just one time, in the `ctor` or the Form's `Load` event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple page print document in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561611/multiple-page-print-document-in-c-sharp)